# Stop drag event during click a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have drag event over a div.image attached.
[image]

when i mouse down on div the drag event start.for this i include nestable.js plugin.i want to stop drag event of div during click on links of div  .i am using js and html file from link: [Nestable](http://dbushell.github.com/Nestable/)

Please give the solution,how can i do it.

Comment: which is the dragging library used?

Answer (score 18):

To ignore handling on click, add "dd-nodrag" class to element.

Comment: Wow, this was the droid I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

author has a problem with nestable plugin. there is some better way to solve the problem of link click that is placed in the nestable container:

```
$(".dd a").on("mousedown", function(event) { // mousedown prevent nestable click
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});

$(".dd a").on("click", function(event) { // click event
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location = $(this).attr("href");
    return false;
});
```

.dd - default nestable container class, change it if you need

Comment: dd-nodrag class didn't work for me but this did. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to prevent the propagation of click event from the link element

Ex:

```
$('#div').on('click', 'a', function(){
    return false;
})
```

Comment: actually, that doesn't work.  nor does event.stopPropagation() and/or event.preventDefault()

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="dd-handle">
ID - Title <a href="#" class="dd-nodrag link_min">Link</a>
```

```
.link_min{
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  right: 0px;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

You can disable this using custom CSS class.

```
.disableDrag{
  display: block;
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 6px 10px 8px 40px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #333333;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
  background: #fbfbfb;
}
```

Use created CSS class on item where you want to disable.

**Working example** [JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/xfnzw3tg/9/)

```
<li class="dd-item"> <div class="disableDrag"><em class="badge pull-right"></em></div> </li>
```